# Ubuntu: file name association

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In Windows command prompt, you can directly type a file name and based on its extension the system launch corresponding applications. For example, C:> foto.jpg (Enter) or C:> doc.pdf (Enter). I wonder if there are similar settings in Ubuntu such as xterm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html):

```
$ xdg-open doc.pdf &
```

It will open the file (or URL) you specify with your preferred application.